# Laptop suddenly reboots mid-game but not in stress-tests?

Tags: windows, laptop, graphics-card, nvidia-graphics-card, reboot

**Note :** My laptop is using a *desktop* GPU and PSU with an *external* GPU adapter. The GPU is *not* a discreet , built-in one.

---

**Symptoms :**

Laptop suddenly reboots in the middle of playing Watch Dogs.External display goes "No Signal" , my earphones give me a horrible crackling noise and the laptop display (BIOS uses the integrated Intel HD) goes "*[Windows Did Not Shut Down Successfully](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0I1cd.jpg)*".

Happens in 20-30 minutes into the game but not  during heated moments; other times runs for hours no problem.

Similar issues found [here](https://www.neowin.net/forum/topic/1356454-pc-reboots-when-playing-games/) and [here](https://forums.tomshardware.com/threads/computer-restarts-like-30-minutes-playing-watch-dogs.1855748/) .

---

**What I've tried and ruled out :**

- Disabled any "*Turn Off Display After*" settings.
- Sucessfully ran overnight for defragging ; no problems with the power button and cables. At this time, it was running from integrated Intel HD.
- MemTest64 found no errors with memory or CPU.
- MSI Kumbostor's "(GL) MSI-01" ruled out GPU or PSU problems.
- The battery icon says " *Plugged in, not charging* " but it looses no charge, this is not the problem.
- I briefly posted an answer that the cause was earphones. But after thorough testing I can see that it crashes regardless.

---

**Setup :**

- Laptop: Panasonic Toughbook CF-53 (*specifically*, CF-53SAPZYC7) with cleanly-installed Windows 7 Pro SP1 64-bit (latest updates and drivers AFAIK)
- CPU: i5-3340M
- RAM: 8GB DDR3 , dual channel
- eGPU adapter : EXP GDC Beast v8 Mini PCI-E
- GPU: GTX 750 [ZT-70704-10M](https://www.zotac.com/us/product/graphics_card/gtx-750-2gb) ; Driver 460.79 (latest)
- PSU: Zebronics 450 W PSU ([ZEB-N450W](https://zebronics.com/products/zeb-n450w-dsata))
- No overclocking whatsoever

---

**EDITS :**

Testing if interference from other devices was the case, by securely wrapping all cables from the exp gdc in aluminium foil. Seems to be promising. At least all glitches and stutters are gone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exp gdc eGPU adapter is known to have extreme sensitivity to any interference. In this case too, interference was the issue.

In my case, I have fixed it by using aluminium foil to wrap around all cables of the adapter. A more permanent solution might be using ferrite beads, though I have not tried it , it seems to work for most people posting on forums.

If you are experiencing similar issues, I would suggest that you attempt insulating the cable from interference using aluminium/ferrite beads second only to checking your PSU. It is easy to do, and if it works, it may save a lot of hassle and money.